# What is the fastest way to get money?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I'm playing Dragon Quest IX, and I'm at the part where I just got the boat. What is the fastest way to make a bunch of money? I need about 10,000 to buy the best equipment and grinding takes a really long time when you only get a few hundred per enemy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Early on the game, the best technique is to fight the highest level monsters that you have access to.

Here are some more techniques:

- **Gold Golems**, which you can find in the ditch south of Gleeba, drop 505 gold each.
- Use Alchemy to make **Ear Cosys** (Fur Hood + Bunny Tail + Lambswool) and sell them.  You can buy the ingredients at Slurry Quay (Fur Hood), Porth Llaffan (Bunny Tail) and Batsureg (Bunny Tail).
- Use Alchemy to make **Gold Mails** (Silver Mail + Gold Ring + Gold Bracer) and sell them.  You can buy the ingredients at Bloomingdale (Silver Mail) and Porth Llaffan (Gold Ring and Gold Bracer).
- In mid level (Copper, Bronze, Steel, Silver, and Gold) Cave and Ruin grottoes, you might find **Gem Jamborees** - these are worth 1130 gold each, and drop Gleeban Gold Pieces or Gold Bars.
- In high level (Platinum, Ruby, Emerald, Sapphire or Diamond) Ice (Snowhall, Tundra, Glacier) and Ruin (Crypt, Ruins, Path, Maze, Lair, World) grottoes, you might find **Gem Slimes** - these are worth 10080 gold each.

(Most of these techniques require finishing certain points of the game.)

Comment: Where are the gold golems?

Comment: I'm told they "in the ditch south of Gleeba".

Comment: @Apreche In Gleeba west of the desert on an island.

Answer (score 1):

I choose to make ear cosies. Killing gold golems are more fun but is not very efficient.
I am pretty sure making gooey gear is most efficient.
To get a lot of slimedrops I go to the plateau by Angel Falls and kill slimes.

Answer (score 0):

I just fight grotto bosses. It's inefficient I'm sure,  but you got lots of exp. and a nice bit of gold, and sometimes nice drops (especially legaxy bosses)

Answer (score -3):

Grinding takes a while, but I made 16,500 gold in an hour battling non-stop.

Faffing about using alchemy and buying ingredients will take just as long, and you don't get any of the experience you'd get from battling, so it's an easy choice, really.

Comment: Once you have 96000 or so gold, you can make 99 Ear Cosies. That gets you about 22000 gold and takes maybe 5 minutes. It's much faster than battling.

Comment: and gold armor is even faster, but takes a lot more starting gold